# jQuery highlight row based on several row cells

Tags: jquery

I see many questions on highlighting based on a cell value, but how would I cycle through the Nth to the Nth row cell and then highlight the row?

Specifically, I want to check if cells 2 to 4 are empty and highlight the row if they are:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
    <th>Col 3</th>
    <th>Col 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Pseudo code :

```
for each TR {
    blankvariable = true
    for each cell from 2 to 4 {
       if not empty then blankvariable = false
    }
    if blankvariable = true then highlight row
}
```

In my example, Row 2 would be highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple, all you need to do is to get all tds from the current context in the loop and call its parents, then loop against all columns and filter only the range we want to work with.

Here's an example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table tbody tr').each(function()
  {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $columns = $this.find('td');
    blankvariable = true;

    $columns.each(function(index){
       if(index > 0 && index <= 3)
       {
          if($(this).text() !== '')
          {
             blankvariable = false;
          }
       }             
    });

    if(blankvariable)
    {
       $this.css({
        backgroundColor: 'lightblue'
       });
    } 
  });
});
```

I created a fiddle to demonstrate it working https://jsfiddle.net/7fLyhfwx/

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach following your pseudocode, demonstrating how to get also some useful information about rows & columns in your table, considering also spaces and nested markup:

```
// Get information about rows & columns
var totalCells = $("table tr").children().length;
var numHeaders = $("table th").length;
var numRows = $("table tr").length;
var numCells = totalCells - numHeaders;
// We can also detect a potential issue
//  if totalCells div numHeaders doesn't match, some cells are spanned

// Loop over rows
$("table tr").each(function(index) {
  // Filter for td will return 0 during the first row loop
  var cols = $(this).children("td"), numCols = cols.length;
  // Disallow check for header
  var emptyRow = numCols > 0;
  // Loop columns
  for (var c = 0; c < numCols; c++) {
    // Just check cells after the first will be enough
    if (c > 0) {
      var cell = cols[c];
      // Consider nested span's and &nbsp;
      var content = $(cell).text().trim();
      if (content.length > 0) {
        emptyRow = false;
        // Don't need additional check anymore
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (emptyRow) {
    $(this).fadeIn("slow").css("background", "yellow");
  }
});
```